# How to get a list of users that can log in locally on Windows?

Tags: windows, authentication

Is there a way to enumerate all users on a local (NT-based) Windows box that can log in locally? Basically, I need a list of non-system users - this includes Administrator but excludes SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE and NETWORK SERVICE.

Edit: Yes, I need to do this from code. Since this is a programming website, I thought this was implied.

Comment: Not-Programming-related.

Comment: Since this is a programming website, I thought it was implied that I needed to do it from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NET USER
[username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
         username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
         username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]

NET USER creates and modifies user accounts on computers. When used
without switches, it lists the user accounts for the computer. The
user account information is stored in the user accounts database.
```

Did you want to do it from code? The following discussion might help:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/EnumerateLocalUser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Net apis.
See MSDN samples

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetQueryDisplayInformation API, combine with bitwise check on user info flag. I have exactly same requirement, so I cook a sample code (modified from MSDN GROUP query).

The user flag I used are UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD ---> this ensure we get Human account, Human account always requires password.

working code at: http://www.cceye.com/list-system-normal-user-account-only/